# download file and then leave page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
$http.post('@Url.Action("donePressed")',
{
    id: $scope.id,
}).then(
function (response) // success callback
{
    window.location = '@Url.Action("PdfCreator", "someController")?Id=' + $scope.id;
    window.location='@Url.Action("Index","AnotherController")';
},
function (response) // failure callback
{
    alert(response.statusText);
});
```

Hi, I guess I am doing somehting wrong, I want to call to a function the sends me a file as a response, and afterwords I want to leave the page and go somewhere else.
the problem is, because this is a sync I don't get my download.

How can I make this synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async has nothing to do with it. Once you're inside the success callback, the async part is already done. The problem is that you're changing the window location again before the first change has had time to load. In other words, it's the exact opposite of an async problem; the problem is that this code is synchronous and runs too fast.

However, the approach here is flawed to begin with. It *might* work if the browser was forced to download the file, as the then the first change to `window.location` would not itself cause the browser view to change. Since PDF is typically a browser-viewable type, this is not guaranteed, though. Regardless, you still have the same issue of need to delay the second call until the first has gotten a response, which is basically impossible. There's no built in event for this type of thing, so the best you'd could do would be to is use `setTimeout` with a 1-2 second delay, and just hope that that is enough time to get the first response. Even then, if it ever took longer, your code would break again. In other words, it's going to be extremely brittle.

The simple fact is that this is just simply not how HTTP works. You're basically trying to return two responses for a single request, which is not possible. This is a clever way to try to skirt around inherent restrictions in the protocol, I'll give you that, but it's ultimately still insufficient.

All that said, you *can* actually make this happen via the HTML5 File API and AJAX, but your solution then will only be compatible with modern browsers (basically everything except IE 10 and under). If you do not need to support lesser versions of IE, then you can use the following code instead:

```
function (response) // success callback
{
    $http.get('@Url.Action("PdfCreator", "someController")?Id=' + $scope.id').then(
        function (response) // success callback
        {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            window.location = '@Url.Action("Index","AnotherController")';
        },
        function (response) // failure callback
        {
            alert(response.statusText);
        }
    );
},
```

The secret sauce is in fetching the PDF via AJAX and then creating an object URL out of the PDF data. You can then use that to create an anchor element in the DOM and "click" it dynamically to prompt the download. The caveat, though, is that I haven't tried to do this with Angular, so I'm unsure if `$http` supports getting a binary response. I know with jQuery, you just have to tell it that the XHR object's response type is 'blob', but I'm not sure if you can or how you would do the same thing with Angular. As an alternative, you can simply use `XMLHttpRequest` directly for this particular AJAX, and simply set `xhr.responseType = 'blob'`.